# Object Detection with moving camera

Tags: opencv, object-detection, background-subtraction

I understand that with a moving object and a stationary camera, it is easy to detect objects by subtracting the previous and current camera frames. It is also possible to detect moving objects when the camera is moving freely around the scene. 
But is it possible to detect stationary objects with a camera rotating around the object? The movement of the camera is predefined and the camera is only restricted to the specified path around the object.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with your problem particulars a little more? What type of object? In the same vein as detecting a moving object in a stationary frame with subtraction, you could find the things that *aren't* moving much.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Objects of focus would mainly be food items. the problem is that nothing in the area of interest would be in motion expect for the camera. So, i dont see how i can use frame subtraction to find the object i need.

Comment: If the camera is rotating around a specific object then almost by definition the object is in the center of the frame and every pixel in the image would be moving faster the farther it is from the central object. I think you should post an example video if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Try camshift demo which locates in opencv source code with this path: samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp. Or other algorithms like meanshift,KCF,etc. These are all object tracking algorithms.